# Istio Envoy proxy cpu resources

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, istio, istio-sidecar

We would like to use Istio for our workload in a production environment. The required CPU resources are documented here: https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/performance-and-scalability/

The documentation uses a load test scenario consisting of 1000 requests per second going through envoy proxies (among other parameters). We do have a much lower number of requests, and of course it is important to optimize CPU resources in order to optimize the cost of our solution.

So, the question is: can we reduce the CPU assignment to the envoy proxies proportionally to the reduction of parameters in our scenario? There is a minimum threshold for CPU assignment? I have found nothing about this in the documentation. Of course, we would like to keep a reasonable small latency added by the proxy (similar to the 2.65 ms in the documented scenario).

We can perform some load testing for our solution once we have Istio running; but the CPU additional resources consumed by Istio will be one of the relevant points in deciding whether to go with it or not. So some initial idea about this would be wonderful.